# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat and multi languages

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, internationalization

I'm using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` on a date that use some text like "April 15, 2016"

It's perfectly working as long as I'm using English culture.

> April 15, 2016 -> ok

My code is set as WordPress plugin. Please understand that I have no control over the component that give me the date (as text) and the WordPress settings. If user set the WordPress installation on another language, the date will change from "April 15, 2016" to let's say (if French) "Avril 15, 2016".

It looks like that `DateTime::createFromFormat()` don't support other language than English so "April 15, 2016" will end up with:

> "Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on boolean"

Did somebody have an idea how we can handle month date as text in several language? Using `DateTime::createFromFormat()` or another method in php?

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate “I have no control over the component that give me the date”? If you describe the plugin, maybe we can find a better solution. I think that in fact you can obtain not-localized info about your date.

Comment: Hello, I get the information back from a POST value from http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ And the culture is set by WP admin.

Comment: If you take a look at [pickadate.js docs](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#formats), you can see that it has a `formatSubmit` option: use this option and your problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks but I have no control on the component nor the CMS, I'm just in the other side of the interface. I just catch the value in like a "hook" / "trigger", from a 3rd party how use this. So the question is "Did somebody have an idea how we can handle month date as text in several language? " Thanks

Comment: You have to spend some time to describe **in details** your plugin and the **context** (editing question, not in the comments), otherwise it is only a waste of time. Basically, in php you can resolve that using `strptime` with `setlocale`, but in your specific case there are a lot of undefined variables: the wordpress locale (you can retrieve it?), the localized strings (that in wp is not the same of php), the date format (in pickadate.js this format is based on wp config? it is customized by user? it is a factory setting?). This is only a short list of sub questions invoked by your question.

Comment: In other words: If you want to know how translate 'Avril 15, 2016' in a valid datetime, the solution is easy. If you want to know how translate a variable date with a variable format with a variable locale, you have to know how retrieve these variables.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this, but both depend on how exactly the input is generated ...

1. Maintain an array of month name translations

This is the simple/naive and most obvious way, I don't think the way to do this needs explaining.

However, depending on how WordPress (and/or the plugin that you're using) works, it may also be your only option.

2. The `IntlDateFormatter` class

This is the purely programmatic way and therefore what would be considered the "proper" one, but unfortunately this class comes as part of a PECL extension - [intl](https://secure.php.net/intl) - and isn't bundled with PHP.

It also requires that you know the language being used before parsing the date, but that shouldn't be a problem as that is how all localization solutions should work in the first place, so I assume this information is available to you in WordPress.
pickdate.js also [seems to work with standard locales by default](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/tree/3.5.6/lib/translations).

That being said, here's how it works:

```
// See http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime
$inputFormat = 'MMMM dd, yyyy';
$inputDate   = 'Avril 15, 2016';
$locale      = 'fr_FR';

// Here comes the magic ...
$dateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    $locale,
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG, // Not really important, may even be NONE
    IntlDateFormatter::NONE, // Time ... we're not using it
    NULL, // Will use date_default_timezone_get()
    NULL, // Calendar; we don't need it
    $inputFormat
);

// Will return bool(false) on failure, use getErrorMessage() for debugging
$unixTimestamp = $dateFormatter->parse($inputDate);
```

It's worth noting that `IntlDateFormatter` is designed mainly for creating localised *outputs* (and rightly so - you shouldn't be parsing a translated month name in the first place, or a name at all for that matter; numbers FTW), so we are indeed writing a lot of irrelevant stuff here.
For your use case, only the `$locale` and `$inputFormat` parameters matter.

There's one more caveat though - we need a *timezone*!
You can get it via (preferrably) `$dateFormatter->getTimeZone()` or in this case just `date_default_timezone_get()`, but you do need the timezone for two reasons:

1. You don't have a *time* value in your input, so `IntlDateFormatter::parse()` assumes "00:00:00".
2. UNIX timestamps are *always* in UTC, so `IntlDateFormatter::parse()` will take that into account and `DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $unixTimestamp)` will set the object's timezone to UTC!

If you're in another timezone, and more specifically in one on the east side of the world, this will happen:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $unixTimestamp);
var_dump($dateTime->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2016-04-14" !!!

$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
var_dump($dateTime->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2016-04-15"
```

You *could* tell `IntlDateFormatter` that you're in UTC in the first place, but that's technically cheating (wink) and depending on what you're using `$dateTime` for later, it may cause side-effects.